# Iphone 5s not taking cookies

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies

This is some code that sends you to another website
with a cookie.

It works fine on my computer but the cookie doesn't get set on my iphone 5s.

```
<form action="test.php">
    <button onclick="setCookie()">go to other site with cookie</button>
</form>

<script>
    let setCookie = function(){
        document.cookie = 'chocolatechip=test';
    }
</script>
```

I have made a server which shows the data sent and received,
this is an example of what i get from my computer(linux if it matters)

```
Get /
```

host 19.234.231.42
cookie chocolatechip = test

this is an example of what i get from my phone(i have cookies enabled and i turned all of my sercurty off.

```
get /
host 012.2341.5345.34
```

Its basically a normal get request without a cookie.

there is no php